# Query list of IDs for value not in table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteriaquery

I have a List of IDs, that I'd like to filter for values that are not present in the database table.

Something like this:

```
SELECT ids
FROM   (VALUES('id1'),
              ('id2'),
              ('id3'),
              ('id4')) I(ids)  
EXCEPT
SELECT ids
FROM Users
```

Is there a way to do this with criteria query?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

We will create a string sql with n positional parameters, create a jpa query object, set the parameters and then execute the query to get the resultList as needed.

```
String queryString = "SELECT ids FROM Users WHERE ids NOT IN (";
//assuming idList is list of ids to exclude
for (int i =0; i<idList.size();++i)
     queryString +=i==0?"?":",?";
queryString +=");"

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, String.class);

for (int i =0; i<idList.size();++i)
     query.setString(idList[i]);
List<String> result= query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thank you Silesh, but this is not using the criteria query API.

Answer (score 0):

That's not directly possible. You will have to query the ids matching the list you have and find out what is missing yourself:

```
var q = cb.createQuery(Integer.class);
var u = q.from(Users.class);
q.select(u.get("id"));
q.where(u.get("id").in(ids));

var list = em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
ids.removeAll(list);
// Now ids contains the ids that are missing
```